# Appending to list returns "list indices must be integers, not unicode" (django/python)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to append an object to a list, and I keep getting the error `list indices must be integers, not unicode`. It doesn't make any sense to me, as I'm not manipulating the list indices in any way... I'm just creating a new list and append()ing objects to it.

Voila:

```
def read(self, request, uid, month, year):
    qs = NewLesson.objects.filter(student__teacher = request.user).filter(endDate__gte=date(int(year), int(month), 1)).filter(startDate__lte=datetime.date(int(year), int(month), calendar.mdays[month]))
    lessonList = []
    qsList = list(qs)
    for l in qsList:
        if l.frequency == 0:
            x = EachLesson()
            x.lessonID = l.id
            x.actualDate = l.startDate
            x.student = l.student
            lessonList.append(x)
        else:
            sd = next_date(l.startDate, l.frequency, datetime.date(int(year), int(month), 1))
            while (sd <= date(int(year), int(month), calendar.mdays[month])):
                x = EachLesson()
                x.lessonID = l.id
                x.actualDate = sd
                x.student = l.student
                lessonList.append(x)
                sd += datetime.timedelta(recurrence)

    return lessonList
```

Assume for the sake of this example that NewLesson and EachLesson have similar structures in the model.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Unfortunately, that *was* the whole traceback. Frustrating.

Comment: @MatthewCalabresi: No, the full traceback would include line numbers and function calls. You just posted the IndexError exception, and even left out the name of the error.

Comment: On a different matter: avoid using a variable named as "l" with all your forces. It is downright hard to read, and in some environments even  impossible to distinguish from the digit "1 " - it just puts unnecessar urden into reading your code.

Comment: @Joel Cornett actually, there wasn't a traceback. Just a blank page with an error message. Apologies for leaving out the name of the error, but it seemed redundant in this case.

jsbueno, thank you for the advice on variable naming.

Comment: @MatthewCalabresi: My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the big hint is the *only* place you've done a getitem call: `mdays[month]`

If you had to convert `month` to an `int` in other places, `month` is most likely a string causing the error on `calendar.mdays[month]`

Otherwise, it's a call elsewhere that your traceback would have identified. My money is on `mdays[month]` though due to the `int(month)` elsewhere.

Comment: That's the one -- I was hung up looking for the error in the list that I declared; the lack of a verbose traceback wasn't the most helpful. Thanks.